# ASP.NET MVC routing maps Q&A

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have working with ASP.NET MVC for 8 months give or take. I know basic routing and how it works but I have few questions in my mind.

First , I have to explain what I know , right? So for instance in the below routing I know the pattern and how it works.

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Categories",
 "category/{CategoryName}",
/*If I use 'mysite.com/category/anything'  
it will look into the 'News' controller and 
then Category action with the given 
parameter('anything') in the category 
action's with the same name parameter. 
EG. public ActionResult Category(Anytype CategoryName) { ... }
*/
 new { controller = "News", action = "Category", CategoryName = "" },
 new string[] { "MyProj.Controllers" } //it is for specifying specific 
//Namespace, mostly used for distinguishing between area routing and regular routing
    );
```

Now if in the above example I had method like

```
public ActionResult Category(Anytype CategoryName2)
```

**Above route won't work because param name does not match.** However, if I submitted a FORM from the category action to the same name action like:

```
[HttpPOST]
public ActionResult Category(ModelType Anyname){...}
```

It works just fine. However, if **I submit a FORM from another place does it work?**

Another thing, when we use the [HttpGET] annotation it can receive any params , there is no restrictions , so why only restrictions on the non action-verb annotated actions? Can anyone please briefly explain this fact?

As an example , my this post can help what I mean. I had change the route at last to make it work.

[Is it possible/right to use multiple @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in 2 different forms in one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341725/is-it-possible-right-to-use-multiple-html-antiforgerytoken-in-2-different-for)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: have you tried with the submitting from another form?

Comment: as far as I remembered I , I tried ajax 'post' from another place with some different params which wasn't defined in my routing maps and it won't work.

Comment: Your question is a difficult to fully understand.  The way you organized your post leads one to believe that you know the problem you are having is with routing.  However, your question, as I've read it, leads me to feel the issue is simply with how you are posting your form from another controller to the referenced action.  Can you please clarify the answer so more of us can understand and attempt to solve the issue?

Comment: Hello, I think this link can help you what I meant. To solve this I had change my route.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341725/is-it-possible-right-to-use-multiple-html-antiforgerytoken-in-2-different-for

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
public ActionResult Category(Anytype CategoryName2)
```

with

```
public ActionResult Category(Anytype CategoryName)
```

Its because you have specified the argument with the name of "CategoryName" in your route and your are using "CategoryName2".

Comment: Thank you for your help but I already know that. Please read the full post to understand what I need to know.

Comment: @user1542653, you said "It won't work with this route" mean you route is not working. That's why i have given this answer.